# AngularJS how can I use the default behavior for an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In angularjs, when I use an `a` tag, I am really using the [`a` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aa) which prevents the default behavior of reloading the page.  However, in my case, I want the link to take me to my /api/logout path, which requires an actual GET request.  In other words, I just want it to work like a normal anchor tag.  How can I do this?

Comment: Are you not using href to do that?

Comment: Using href still prevents the default behavior and uses pushState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be referring to `ng-non-bindable`. Angular will not compile (ignore) elements with this attribute.

Here is the angular documentation on this:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngNonBindable